# "Error: Configuration property is not defined" on `heroku local web` - Config / Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis, config, dotenv

I am trying to setup locally an existing Heroku app. To do so, I `git cloned` the app from our repo in Github. Then I added the `git remote` for heroku.

Normally, builds to the server happen with `Travis CI`, but now I want to run the app locally straight from `heroku`.

`heroku config` returns the config variables just fine.

But `heroku local web` returns the error

> throw new Error('Configuration property "' + property + '" is not defined');
>
> Error: Configuration property "redis.url" is not defined

**redis.js**

```
import config from 'config';
const redis = new Redis(config.get('redis.url'), {
  keyPrefix: 'kw:',
});
```

The `config` folder is in the root of my repo.

**config/default.js**

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config({ silent: true });

module.exports = {
  ...,
  redis: {
    url: process.env.REDIS_URL || process.env.REDISCLOUD_URL,
  },
  ...
}
```

Relevant scripts in **package.js**

```
    "start:server": "./node_modules/.bin/babel-node src/server.js",
    "start:worker": "./node_modules/.bin/babel-node src/worker/worker.js",
    "start": "./node_modules/.bin/nf start",
```

If I run `npm run start:server` I get the same error.

If I comment out the `redis.url` code I get the same error but for another variable in the `config`.

What am I missing? Let me know if you require clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a local `.env` file.

I got confused because I was reading that you dont need a `.env` file with Heroku. But this is not the case for local setups it seems.

Comment: wish there were more clarify here. confused, seems like exactly the point of `heroku local` is that you don't need to create your own .env... still don't understand this. hardcoded these values doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

`heroku config -s > .env`

will copy those files to the local .env it seems. seems strange that this isn't the default, but so it goes.

Once you do that, run your app with `heroku local`.

I found the answer here: https://www.debugcn.com/en/article/31153943.html